# How to make the font of each bold character in a document 4 points bigger

Tags: vba, ms-word

I already have the following code that deletes the paragraph following and entirely bold paragraph (i.e. clearing blank lines after subheadings). I've been trying to amend it to create another macro that increases the font size of every bold character by 4 points.

```
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim searchRange As Range

Set searchRange = Selection.Range
searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

    For Each para In searchRange.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.Font.Bold = True Then para.Next.Range.Delete
    Next para
```

This is what I tried to do, but kept getting a "method or data member not found" error on "Range" in "If char.Range.Font.Bold = True" below, and I'm not well enough versed in VBA to know what the actual problem is. Can I not use Characters to search each character in a document? Does Characters work differently to Paragraphs? To my uninformed brain it seems like I could just switch out parts of the macro above (searching every paragraph) to make it apply to what I'd like to do here (search every character).

```
Dim char As Characters
Dim searchRange As Range

Set searchRange = Selection.Range
searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

    For Each char In searchRange.Paragraphs
        If char.Range.Font.Bold = True Then
            char.Font.Size = char.Font.Size + 4
    Next char
```

I'm not married to the bit about the search range, I'm happy for it to search from the cursor to the end, or just search the whole document, I just copied the other code to try to increase my chances of it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the code in the question, that aren't really intuitive to recognize.

1. There is no `Character` data type in the Word object model, only `Characters`
2. A `Character` object is of the data type `Range` So: `Dim char as Range`
3. A `Character` object is not equivalent to a `Paragraph` object, so the `For...Each` enumeration `For Each char in searchRange.Paragraphs` triggers a "Type Mismatch". It's necessary to loop `searchRange.Characters`.

The following compiles and runs for me:

```
Dim char As Word.Range
Dim searchRange As Range

Set searchRange = Selection.Range
searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.content.End

    For Each char In searchRange.Characters
        If char.Font.Bold = True Then
            char.Font.Size = char.Font.Size + 4
        End If
    Next char
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to highlight it before posting but I forgot, and then I learned I can't highlight, so I've amended the post. searchRange.Characters still returns that same error message on the same "Range". It seems all the things I've tried keep returning the same error on that "Range", and I don't know why.

Comment: @CatJ Thanks for editing in the line that causes the error. The code in the question triggers *two* errors, my original answer caught the second one... I've edited the Answer to cover both.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this. Find and Replace will do this job. Set *Find what* to search for **bold formatting** at the size of the current text, then set *Replace with* to a size that is 4 points larger. Even if you have several different text sizes, it's faster to run a find and replace several times than write a macro.

Comment: I'm including it into another universal macro that does a bunch of other formatting things, to documents whose fonts range from 12 to 72 point, with the idea that one keystroke does as much as possible to reduce human intervention.

Comment: A VBA find and replace will do the same, but it can programmatically adjust to the font size. As a Word pro, though, I have to point out that you should be finding text samples and replacing them with _styles_ instead of locally increasing their size. That's the real key to making documents that are efficient to work with in the long run. For this example, you would create a character style, then apply that to all bold text.

Comment: Styles affect the entire paragraph though which I don't want to do, as some are normal paragraphs that contain some bold (for example for emphasis).

Comment: Only partially true. Paragraph styles affect entire paragraphs. Character styles affect selected text, not whole paragraphs. Linked styles work as both paragraph and character styles.

Comment: So Find & Replace with .Wrap = wdFindContinue, searching only for bold formatting, and then applying a character style that's 4 points bigger than normal? Would that F&R alone with wdFindContinue apply the style to every bold character in the entire document?

Comment: Word documents are broken onto parts called Stories. To find every bold character, you would have to search every story. Here's an article with more details: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/FindReplaceAllWithVBA.htm

Comment: @Catj It's never a good idea to use wdFindContinue when performing a F/R using VBA. That coul cause an infintie loop. Either Find/Replace ALL if that works, or use a Do-Loop (lots of examples of that here and elsewhere) to repeat the Find until .Execute returns False.